# Proof $($by contradiction$)$

Tags: proof-explanation

can anyone please explain through these? If so, I would really appreciate it. I think one, if not both, are proof by contradiction.

1) Suppose that m and n are negative integers with $m > n$.
Prove that $\sqrt{(m^2 + n^2)} \neq −(m + n)$.

2) Suppose that a and b are rational numbers and $x^2 −ax+b = 0$ has two
distinct real solutions. Prove that one solution is irrational if and only
if the other solution is irrational.

Note; 2 is a Contrapositive as we have not been taught Vieta's as of yet.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: For $2$ , try to use [Vieta's Formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%2527s_formulas&ved=2ahUKEwj4xdOYw4_mAhVtzDgGHZjcDckQFjAOegQICRAg&usg=AOvVaw0dN99SJw7E05_GSB_4ce25)

Answer (score 0):

1) $m,n<0\implies 2mn>0\implies m^2+2mn+n^2>m^2+n^2\implies -(m+n)>\sqrt{m^2+n^2}.$

2) By Vieta, if $x_0$ is a root, the other is $x_1=a-x_0$. With $a$ rational, $x_0,x_1$ are of the same type.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I understand all of the first answer, excluding where the negative comes from in the final form?
I'll update the question in a second, but apparently the second one is a Contrapositive. Thank you either way though

Comment: @Wheatbread: 1) for negatives, $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$; 2) no, this is a straight proof.